# Too Many Connections Error on RDS MySql via EC2 Jenkins

Tags: mysql, maven, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm getting a too many connections error when accessing my AWS RDS MySql through my EC2 Jenkins server on when doing maven clean install (when running the tests), This doesn't happen when i run it locally, also accessing RDS.

I tried increasing the Max_Connections in the RDS configuration to no avail.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>plenty</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RC2</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Hibernate / jpa -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Needed in XML processing for Wagnet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GeoTools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geometry</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.wimpi</groupId>
        <artifactId>telnetd-x</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- project lombok -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jsr-275, used for measurements -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.measure</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr-275</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optaplanner -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaplanner-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.CR4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- apache commons -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.rdthree.plenty.Application</start-class>
    <geotools.version>12-RC1</geotools.version>

</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/scripts</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- <forkCount>1</forkCount> -->
                <!-- <reuseForks>true</reuseForks> -->
                <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=128m</argLine>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.9</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <configuration>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>${mysql.url}</url>
                <username>${mysql.username}</username>
                <password>${mysql.password}</password>
                <forceMojoExecution>true</forceMojoExecution>
                <!-- <settingsKey>mysql</settingsKey> -->
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-schema</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <srcFiles>
                            <srcFile>src/main/scripts/plenty-db.sql</srcFile>
                        </srcFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your max connections by creating a [DB Parameter Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html), applying it to your instance, and changing the parameter there.